# Lucene ranking - how to use new 4.0 scoring models

Tags: lucene

desperately trying to implement a new feature in the Lucene, I'm turning to you.
Basically some additional scoring models have been added to the Lucene in this JIRA isse: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2959

Pardon my ignorance, but I really don't understand how to get that "version" of the lucene as described in that link, so that I can use it for my own needs. The authors in that link mention that they've implemented new ranking models such as BM25, but I don't know where to get the source code, nor how to implement or run the Lucene with these new functionalities. If you have knowhow on this, your help will be highly appreciated.

thanks in advance,

Nik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there is no official / unofficial release date for lucene 4.0 if you want to use the latest and greatest features you need to checkout trunk of use a nightly build.

http://lucene.apache.org/core/developer.html

> svn checkout http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk lucene_trunk

This should get you 4.0 and of course, the features you want:

- http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/ -- BM25Similarity, etc.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by sdolgy, you should pull a nightly build:

Lucene: http://lucene.apache.org/core/developer.html
Solr: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/NightlyBuilds

as far as how to use these models, its pretty simple.

From Lucene, set the similarity on your IndexSearcher:

```
indexSearcher.setSimilarity(new BM25Similarity());
```

From Solr, set the similarity in schema.xml:

```
<similarity class="solr.BM25SimilarityFactory"/>
```

More advanced configurations are possible (e.g. setting parameters, per-field configuration, etc).

For Lucene, start with an overview from the package documentation:
https://builds.apache.org/view/G-L/view/Lucene/job/Lucene-trunk/javadoc/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/package-summary.html

For Solr, take a look at the javadocs of the various factories:
https://builds.apache.org/view/G-L/view/Lucene/job/Solr-trunk/javadoc/org/apache/solr/search/similarities/package-summary.html

If you need more advanced Solr configuration examples, have a look at the tests in http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/core/src/test-files/solr/conf/

For example, this test file uses SchemaSimilarityFactory to configure different DFR models on different fields so that it can easily test that various combinations are working, (I am *not* recommending you go and configure completely different scoring systems for each field unless you know what you are doing, its just possible, and has some examples of how to configure the factory): http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/core/src/test-files/solr/conf/schema-dfr.xml

Similar tests for other models' factories exist in this directory, too:
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/core/src/test-files/solr/conf/schema-bm25.xml, http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/core/src/test-files/solr/conf/schema-ib.xml, http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/core/src/test-files/solr/conf/schema-lmdirichlet.xml, http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/core/src/test-files/solr/conf/schema-lmjelinekmercer.xml, http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/core/src/test-files/solr/conf/schema-tfidf.xml

Comment: Hi Robert, 
I compolied the downloaded lucene with ant, and build was successful. It produced 'lucene-core-4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'. What I did, I simply removed my lucene-core-3.0.2 lib and just added the new one. However, I get many errors with the imports. Also, where do I set `indexSearcher.setSimilarity(new BM25Similarity());`?

Comment: `StandardAnalyzer` is missing in the snapshot version 4.0 :(. How should I replace this?

Comment: Hello, sorry but these questions are a little out of scope here. Lucene 4.0 is a new "major release" with both a modularized core library, refactoring across lucene and solr, new flexible indexing & scoring apis, the list goes on and on. Its extremely important to read the provided CHANGES.txt and MIGRATE.txt, this is no drop-in upgrade.

Comment: I checked the code in http://search-lucene.com/jd/lucene/org/apache/lucene/analysis/package-summary.html though the standard analyzer is used there, I can't find it anywhere. Also the link to the standardanalyzer in that API is broken. I simply need to used lucene for my research purposes, without having to dig in deep into it, and I'm migrating from 3.0.2 because of BM25.
Oh, one more thing, I checked your slides at http://www.lucidimagination.com/sites/default/files/file/Eurocon2011/Muir_Eurocon_ImprovedSearchLucene4.pdf, I was wondering what program did you use to create such charts?

Comment: Nik, maybe you want to get active on the Lucene mailing lists with those questions...!

Answer (score 1):

Checkout from trunk. If the feature you want is not there, you need a need a patch of Lucene or a nightly build. As the patch for your feature is already there, you can check this out and follow the instructions to apply your patch to the lucene build you are using:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HowToContribute#Review.2BAC8-Improve_Existing_Patches

```
cd {your.checkout.of.lucene.dir}
svn up
wget "https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12493806/LUCENE-2959.patch" -O - | patch -p0
```

which will apply the patch to your build of Lucene.

Comment: haha :) I am also running win7 at work (not for long). What you need to do is get some sort of an svn client (maybe tortoise svn, if you are running win7, make it easy), checkout the latest build of lucene. Then you download the patch from the link and use tortoise svn to apply the patch.