# Setting a df threshold, beyond which, query terms should be ignored

Tags: search, solr, lucene, tf-idf

I am using Solr to search and index products from a database. Products have two interesting fields : a name and a description. Product names are normally unique,  but sometimes contain common words,  which serve as a pre-description of the product. One example would be "UltraScrew -  a motor powered screwdriver”. Names are generally much shorter than descriptions

The problem is that when one searches for a common term, documents that contain it in the name get an unwanted boost, over those that contain it only in the description. This is due to the fact that names are shorter, and even with the normalization added afterwards, it is quite visible.

I was wondering if it is possible to filter terms out of the name, not with a dictionary of stop words, but based on the relative document frequency of the term. That means, if a term appears in more than 10% of the available documents, it should be ignored when the name field is queried. The description field should be left untouched.

Is this generally possible?

Answer (score 2):

maybe you could use your own similarity:

```
import org.apache.lucene.search.Similarity;
public class MySimilarity extends Similarity {

@Override
public float idf(int docFreq, int numDocs) {
    float freq = ((float)docFreq)/((float)numDocs);
    if (freq >=0.1) return 0;
    return (float) (Math.log(numDocs / (double) (docFreq + 1)) + 1.0);
}
...
}
```

and use that one instead of the default one.
You can set the similarity for an indexSearcher at lucene level, see [this other answer to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9595080/101762).

Comment: do you know if it is possible to switch the similarity algorithm at runtime, using SolrJ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood the question correctly, but you could run two separate queries. Pseudo code:

```
SearchResults nameSearchResults = search("name:X");
if (nameSearchResults.size() * 10 >= corpusSize) { // name-based search useless?
   return search("description:X");   // use description-based search
} else {
   return search("name:X description:X); // search both fields
}
```

Comment: Isn't that going to be too performance intensive? I mean, executing two queries every time.

Comment: Depends on your corpus. For small indices, I think the performance loss would be negligible, but you need to measure this yourself.